# compile a simple test with CGAL

Tags: c++, cgal

I have just installed CGAL with brew on a mac system. Now I'm exciting to try it with a simple and minimal example. Ho can I compile it with g++?

I want to compile this sample file with:

```
gcc namefile.cpp -lCGAL -I/usr/local/include/CGAL
```

and I get a lot of errors... (too many to paste it here I think)

as example file I'm using

```
File: examples/Arrangement_on_surface_2/sweep_line.cpp



#include <CGAL/Cartesian.h>
#include <CGAL/MP_Float.h>
#include <CGAL/Quotient.h>
#include <CGAL/Arr_segment_traits_2.h>
#include <CGAL/Sweep_line_2_algorithms.h>
#include <list>

typedef CGAL::Quotient<CGAL::MP_Float>                  NT;
typedef CGAL::Cartesian<NT>                             Kernel;
typedef Kernel::Point_2                                 Point_2;
typedef CGAL::Arr_segment_traits_2<Kernel>              Traits_2;
typedef Traits_2::Curve_2                               Segment_2;

int main()
{
  // Construct the input segments.
  Segment_2 segments[] = {Segment_2 (Point_2 (1, 5), Point_2 (8, 5)),
                          Segment_2 (Point_2 (1, 1), Point_2 (8, 8)),
                          Segment_2 (Point_2 (3, 1), Point_2 (3, 8)),
                          Segment_2 (Point_2 (8, 5), Point_2 (8, 8))};

  // Compute all intersection points.
  std::list<Point_2>     pts;

  CGAL::compute_intersection_points (segments, segments + 4,
                                     std::back_inserter (pts));

  // Print the result.
  std::cout << "Found " << pts.size() << " intersection points: " << std::endl; 
  std::copy (pts.begin(), pts.end(),
             std::ostream_iterator<Point_2>(std::cout, "\n"));

  // Compute the non-intersecting sub-segments induced by the input segments.
  std::list<Segment_2>   sub_segs;

  CGAL::compute_subcurves(segments, segments + 4, std::back_inserter(sub_segs));

  std::cout << "Found " << sub_segs.size()
            << " interior-disjoint sub-segments." << std::endl;

  CGAL_assertion (CGAL::do_curves_intersect (segments, segments + 4));

  return 0;
}
```

#### EDIT:

```
>>> g++ --version
i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-g++-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO

>>> g++ sweep_line.cpp
In file included from /usr/local/include/CGAL/Bbox_2.h:31,
                 from /usr/local/include/CGAL/basic_classes.h:31,
                 from /usr/local/include/CGAL/Cartesian/Cartesian_base.h:29,
                 from /usr/local/include/CGAL/Cartesian.h:28,
                 from sweep_line.cpp:4:
/usr/local/include/CGAL/array.h:81: error: expected nested-name-specifier before '...' token
/usr/local/include/CGAL/array.h:81: error: expected '>' before '...' token
/usr/local/include/CGAL/array.h:83: error: template argument 2 is invalid
/usr/local/include/CGAL/array.h:84: error: expected ',' or '...' before '&' token
/usr/local/include/CGAL/array.h: In function 'int CGAL::make_array(const T&, int)':
/usr/local/include/CGAL/array.h:86: error: template argument 2 is invalid
/usr/local/include/CGAL/array.h:86: error: invalid type in declaration before '=' token
/usr/local/include/CGAL/array.h:86: error: 'args' was not declared in this scope
/usr/local/include/CGAL/array.h:86: error: expected `}' before '...' token
/usr/local/include/CGAL/array.h:86: error: expected `}' before '...' token
/usr/local/include/CGAL/array.h:86: error: expected ',' or ';' before '...' token
/usr/local/include/CGAL/array.h: At global scope:
/usr/local/include/CGAL/array.h:87: error: expected unqualified-id before 'return'
/usr/local/include/CGAL/array.h:88: error: expected declaration before '}' token
    warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.



>>>g++ sweep_line.cpp -lCGAL -I/usr/local/include/CGAL
In file included from /usr/local/include/CGAL/gmpxx_coercion_traits.h:35,
                 from /usr/local/include/CGAL/mpz_class.h:29,
                 from /usr/local/include/CGAL/gmpxx.h:47,
                 from /usr/local/include/CGAL/is_convertible.h:28,
                 from /usr/local/include/CGAL/Rational_traits.h:31,
                 from /usr/local/include/CGAL/number_type_basic.h:65,
                 from /usr/local/include/CGAL/basic.h:36,
                 from /usr/local/include/CGAL/Cartesian/Cartesian_base.h:28,
                 from /usr/local/include/CGAL/Cartesian.h:28,
                 from sweep_line.cpp:4:
/usr/local/include/mpfr.h:181: error: expected ';' before '*' token
/usr/local/include/mpfr.h:279: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before 'const'
/usr/local/include/mpfr.h:280: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before 'const'
/usr/local/include/mpfr.h:281: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before 'int'
/usr/local/include/mpfr.h:282: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before 'int'
/usr/local/include/mpfr.h:283: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before 'int'
/usr/local/include/mpfr.h:284: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before 'const'
/usr/local/include/mpfr.h:286: error: '__GMP_DECLSPEC' does not name a type
/usr/local/include/mpfr.h:287: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before 'int'
/usr/local/include/mpfr.h:288: error: '__GMP_DECLSPEC' does not name a type
/usr/local/include/mpfr.h:289: error: '__GMP_DECLSPEC' does not name a type
/usr/local/include/mpfr.h:290: error: '__GMP_DECLSPEC' does not name a type
/usr/local/include/mpfr.h:291: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before 'int'
/usr/local/include/mpfr.h:292: error: '__GMP_DECLSPEC' does not name a type
/usr/local/include/mpfr.h:293: error: '__GMP_DECLSPEC' does not name a type
/usr/local/include/mpfr.h:295: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before 'void'
/usr/local/include/mpfr.h:296: error: '__GMP_DECLSPEC' does not name a type
/usr/local/include/mpfr.h:297: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before 'const'
/usr/local/include/mpfr.h:300: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before 'void'
/usr/local/include/mpfr.h:301: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before 'void'
/usr/local/include/mpfr.h:302: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before 'void'
/usr/local/include/mpfr.h:303: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before 'void'
/usr/local/include/mpfr.h:304: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before 'void'
```

Comment: Your code compiles just fine for me. Try to use `g++` instead of `gcc`. And add your errors, please.

Comment: here it is, g++ with no argument and with the same argument

Comment: Could you post `/usr/local/include/mpfr.h` to somewhere([pastebin](http://pastebin.com) for example), so I could test with your header?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/VAAJy4pr

Comment: My and your files are same(except version lines). Post, please, `/usr/local/include/CGAL/array.h` file too, I will try to compile with it.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Vzeg5P4b

Comment: Try to add `--std=c++11` or `--std=c++0x` to compiler flags.

Comment: I can't believe to that but i was thinking to already compile with c++0x but no.. i have g++ version 4.2 (with apple llvm backend), because i'm gettin the erro `cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=c++0x"` even with c++11, I need to install a new compiler..

Comment: "_I have g++ version 4.2_" - damn, I forgot about it. Sorry. You could use second way from my answer in that case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two ways:

1. Allow C++11 by adding corresponding flag to compiler(`--std=c++11` or `--std=c++0x`).
2. Define `CGAL_CFG_NO_CPP0X_ARRAY`, `CGAL_CFG_NO_TR1_ARRAY` and `CGAL_CFG_NO_VARIADIC_TEMPLATES`. Note: in this case you will need `boost/array.hpp` header.

Answer (score 4):

You should use
  -I/usr/local/include
instead of
  -I/usr/local/include/CGAL

Comment: This worked for me. I am wokring with Ubuntu 20.04 and Code Blocks.