# Compiling a CGAL example program on Arch Linux with icpc

Tags: c++, archlinux, cgal, icc

I want to compile [an example program with CGAL 4.4](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/QP_solver/QP_solver_2first_qp_8cpp-example.html) on Arch Linux with Intel Compiler.

But, on compiling this code, I got the following error:

```
$ icpc -o first_qp first_qp.cpp -lCGAL -I/usr/include/CGAL
```

[**The error message is here (pastebin)**](http://pastebin.com/E3UAYf1y)

What can I do?

**#** My box is up-to-date and the CGAL and boost library were already installed by pacman.

```
$ sudo pacman -Syu
$ sudo pacman -S cgal boost boost-libs
```

**#** I have already read [an article about a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16462396/compile-a-simple-test-with-cgal), but could not solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove `-I/usr/include/CGAL`. It is not needed, and it confuses the compiler, which reads `/usr/include/CGAL/gmp.h` instead of `/usr/include/gmp.h`. Note that the recommended way to compile CGAL examples is with cmake (see the documentation), which handles all the flags for you.